# Yii2 HttpClient: Access Request instance from Response instance

Tags: yii2

Using [`yii2-httpclient`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient), what is the correct way to access the corresponding [`yii\httpclient\Request`](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient/doc/api/2.0/yii-httpclient-request) instance from the resulting [`yii\httpclient\Response`](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient/doc/api/2.0/yii-httpclient-response) object?

I am trying to write a custom [XML parser](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient/doc/api/2.0/yii-httpclient-xmlparser) which needs to know what URL it is parsing. It does not seem to be possible to access the original `Request` (through which I could [get the URL](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient/doc/api/2.0/yii-httpclient-request#getUrl()-detail)) from a parser instance (only the `Response`).

I have considered utilizing `yii\httpclient\Client::EVENT_AFTER_SEND` to copy the request into a variable, but that would not be thread-safe, so I need a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your parser needs to know URL of request to parse response, it is probably not a parser and you're overusing parser API and `ParserInterface`. I suggest to create some component which will wrap and hide all request-response-parser logic. Then you will be able to implement custom parser and call it manually:

```
public function get($url) {
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->createRequest()
        ->setUrl($url)
        ->send();
    return (new MyParser($url, $response))->getContent();
}
```